# Blackberry gridfield issue

Tags: blackberry

I have a gridfield and i am adding contents to ir. The problem is that the items scroll beyond the gridfield layout. I want the items to be within the gridfield and not go beyond it. Below is the code snippet.

```
gridbackManager = new VerticalFieldManager(
        VerticalFieldManager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL |
        VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL) {

    protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {  
        int c = graphics.getColor();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, bip.getWidth(), bip.getHeight());
        graphics.setColor(c);   
        super.paintBackground(graphics);
    }

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        int width = bip.getWidth();
        int height = bip.getHeight();
        super.sublayout( width, height);
        setExtent( width, height);
    }
};
```

Here bip is a bitmap whose size is 290*220. My screen size is 320*240. So the gridfield dont cover the whole screen but some portion of it.

Comment: What do you mean with beyond? As in you have to scroll to get to the elements?

Comment: @arunabha: It's really unclear what you mean. In such cases a screenshot of what you have and what you'd like to have is a must. Also, for the future please try to format your text/code in a proper way (we are people here, not compilers).

Answer (score -1):

use GridFieldManager instead of all this its a good option in blackberry